# How to get just the number from units?

Tags: command-line, units

The default output of `units` seems to be a bit verbose:

```
$ units "2 fortnight" seconds
    * 2419200
    / 4.1335979e-07
```

Suppose I just want the number only, so that I can do things like `sleep $(units "2 fortnight" seconds)`. Is there a formatting argument for `units` that I'm missing? Or is there some simple way to pipe it into something and get just the number? I can see that `$ units "2 fortnight" seconds | head -n 1` would at least get rid of the factor, but I still have the extra whitespace and `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU Units version 2.19`:

```
$ units --one-line  --compact '2 fortnight' seconds
2419200
```

BSD implementation of `units` doesn't have `--one-line  --compact` but
you can use awk:

```
$ units '2 fortnight' seconds  | awk 'NR == 1 {print $2}'
2419200
```

Comment: It so happens that I'm actually on a Mac, so this didn't work for my ancient version of `units`, but I think it solves the problem and I will accept :)

Comment: I'm on Linux too

Comment: Sorry - I meant on a Mac

Comment: FreeBSD `units` has a `-t, --terse` option to only print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer solves the issue, if you happen to have a very old version of `units` you can also do:

```
$ units "2 fortnight" sec | head -n 1 | grep -E "\d+" --only-matching
2419200
```